# How to organize data for usage by another object?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, arraylist

I have a file that contains sales data like this:

```
2554.22,5321.12,323.29,8283.11,1923.26,6632.46,1104.42
.
.
.
n
```

So the file could contain *n* number of lines.  I need to read the file using a Scanner object and calculate daily, weekly, and the average sales for a given day or week.

So far I've designed it like this:

Data class:

```
public class SalesData  {

   private float[] sales;

   public SalesData(float[] sales) {

      this.sales = sales;
   }

   public float getTotalSales() {

      float totalSales = 0.0;

      for(float sale : sales) {
         totalSales += sale;
      }

      return totalSales;
   }

   public float getAverageSales() {

      return getTotalSales / salesData.length;
   }

}
```

I'm having trouble with my SalesUtil class.  I'm not sure how to get the data from each line and store it in an array so that I can instantiate my SalesData class.  I'm trying to use ArrayList, but I got lost.  I'm not sure if I'm even going down the right path.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
public class SalesUtil {

   public List<String> readSalesFile() {

      List<String> salesAsString = new ArrayList<String>();

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter sales file name: ");
      String salesFile = keyboard.nextLine();

      try {

         Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(salesFile));
         while(scanFile.hasNext()) {
            salesAsString.add(scanFile.nextLine());
         }
      catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
         System.out.println("Invalid file name supplied, please try again.");
         readSalesFile();
      }

      return salesAsString;
   }

   public List<Float> parseSalesFile(List<String> salesFile) {

     List<Float> salesAsFloat = new ArrayList<Float>();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are reading your file one line at a time, which gives you a String for each line.

From that, you'll want to split the string at each `,`, which you can do with `salesLine.split(",")`, which will give you a `String[]` for each line in your file. Then you will want to convert this `String[]` into a `float[]` for use in your `SalesData` class.

Your `parseSalesFile` would be a good place to do this (although you'll probably want to change its signature to `float[] parseSalesFile(List<String> salesFile)` considering your `SalesData` class takes a `float[]` and not a `List<Float>` as input. It would go something like

```
public float[] parseSalesFile(List<String> salesFile) {
    float[] salesAsFloat = new float[salesFile.size() * 7];
    for (int w = 0; w < salesFile.size(); w++) {
        String[] salesByDay = salesFile[w].split(",");
        for (int d = 0; d < salesByDay; d++)
            salesAsFloat[w * 7 + d] = Float.parseFloat(daySales);
    }
    return salesAsFloat;
}
```

You might want to think of a more advanced representation of your data to ease the computation of statistics though, as with a simple array of floats, computing statistics for a given week will require you to first compute the index ranges corresponding to that week.

Comment: Each row represents a given week.  Each column is a day in the week

Comment: OK. Then indeed converting your file into a single `List<Float>` is an option. Depending on your later needs a more complex structure might be interesting though (e.g. having a structure representing sales data for a given day with a reference to the day, so you can more easily compute statistics like "average sales on mondays", etc.); I'll update my answer taking that into account to reduce it to the directly relevant information so that it's clearer.